# How to verify PEM format certificate in Java

Tags: java, certificate, pem

I have PEM format file, How can verify the signature in Java, as I followed http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/versig.html but found that Java doesnt support PEM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a certificate in a PEM file using [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)'s `PEMReader`. If the content is an X.509 certificate, you should get an instance of `X509Certificate` and verify it as you want from there.

**EDIT**: Here is what the code should look like (not tried):

```
// The key with which you want to verify the cert.
// This is probably a CA certificate's public key.
PublicKey publicKey = ...;

PEMReader reader = new PEMReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.pem"));
Object pemObject = reader.readObject();
if (pemObject instanceof X509Certificate) {
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)pemObject;
    cert.checkValidity(); // to check it's valid in time
    cert.verify(publicKey); // verify the sig. using the issuer's public key
}
```

(Of course, as with any I/O operations, you'll need to close the reader perhaps with try/finally.)

Note that `checkValidity` and `verify` don't return anything: instead, they throw exceptions if when they fail.

Comment: As I'm very new to Java, May I havs some kind of code snippet.