# Reading data from a certificate file

Tags: certificate, pfx

I have a local setup of Open SSL. For every certificate request i create a ...cert.pem and ...pfx file.
I need open the cert.pem and the pfx to read the below data
1) Certificate serial id
2) Expiry date
3) Validity date

Is there some API that can help me do this?

Comment: I am looking for a Java based API

Answer (score 0):

You can read PFX (PKCS#12) certificates using JDK API without BouncyCastle:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("foo.pfx"), "passwd".toCharArray());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
...
```

For reading PEM files see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342343/how-to-verify-pem-format-certificate-in-java/6342399#6342399)